# Why is this printing line 10 printing before the output of line 9?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have tried serveral things but im not understanding why 'line 10' execute before 'line 9'.

ACTUAL CODE:

```
 df -PH | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|loop' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 " " $6}' |  while read output;
  do
    proc=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
    mountp=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $3 }' )
    ohostn=$(checkOtherHostname)

    if [ $proc -ge $THRESHOLD_HD ]; then
      printf "%20s [%6s] [%20s] %4s%% \"%s\"\n" "$(hostname)" "$ohostn" "$mountp" "$proc" "$partition"
      sudo du -sh $mountp/*
    fi
  done
```

Result is in the OUTPUT below.

Then I tried differently by putting in a second if statement underneath the first if statement and moved the sudo command in it and the output was still the same!

```
  df -PH | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|loop' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 " " $6}' |  while read output;
  do
    proc=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
    mountp=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $3 }' )
    ohostn=$(checkOtherHostname)

    if [ $proc -ge $THRESHOLD_HD ]; then
      printf "%20s [%6s] [%20s] %4s%% \"%s\"\n" "$(hostname)" "$ohostn" "$mountp" "$proc" "$partition"
    fi

    if [ $proc -ge $THRESHOLD_HD ]; then
      sudo du -sh $mountp/*
    fi
  done
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.1T    /data/svn_repo_01/repos
16K /data/svn_repo_01/lost+found
2.7G    /data/svn_repo_01/csvn
4.0K    /data/svn_repo_01/migration
4.0K    /data/svn_repo_01/tmp
            vmappp21 [svntoy] [   /data/svn_repo_01]   70% "/dev/sde1"
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It shouldn't happen.

I couldn't reproduce your issue on my environment, but you didn't give us some relevant information:

- bash --version. E.g. `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- What `checkOtherHostname` does?
- If the current stdout is being redirected in a higher level (e.g. through pipes or using `exec >`)

**About performance**

Nothing to do with your question, but I noticed you used the folowing commands:

- df, grep (one execution)
- awk (4 times: 3 executions for each `df` row)
- cut, echo, hostname and checkOtherHostname (one execution for each `df` row)
- printf, sudo, du (when proc >= THRESHOLD_HD)

As it's a small script without special performance needs, that shouldn't be a problem, but if you intend to use the same approach in bigger scripts or processing many records. It can be an issue.

So I made this reduced version of your script, using only the minimal quantity of commands:

- df, hostname and checkOtherHostname (one time)
- printf, sudo, du (when proc >= THRESHOLD_HD)

```
hostname="$(hostname)"
ohostn="$(checkOtherHostname)"
df -PH | while read partition size used avail proc mountp; do
    if ! [[ "$partition$mountp" =~ "Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom|loop" ]] && [ ${proc%%%} -ge $THRESHOLD_HD ]; then
        printf "%20s [%6s] [%20s] %4s \"%s\"\n" "$hostname" "$ohostn" "$mountp" "$proc" "$partition"
        sudo du -sh $mountp/*
    fi
done
```